# How to create or import a KEY when deploy Azure Key Value using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

We can create secrets when deploy KV using ARM template, but it can't seem to create or import a KEY at the same time. Is anybody know how to create a KEY when deploying the KV? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of now, unfortunately. You can only create secrets with ARM templates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's **not available to create Keys** when deploy azure keyvault via ARM Template and you could **only create secrets** when deploy keyvault.

You could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906355-azure-key-vault/suggestions/34256263-create-key-vault-keys-via-arm-template) to promote the feature to achieve.

Comment: totally not a duplicate of existing answer ;)

Comment: I am also watching this case, but the reply is slower than you.

Comment: so it's a duplicate :)

Comment: But I am more completely than you. So I think it's no violation of rules.